# C++03 Initialization of an Array of Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, initialization, c++03

I'm sure this is a dupe, but I can't seem to find any information on this prior to C++11.

If I have an Plain Old Data (POD) type:

```
class Foo {
    double x, y, z;
};
```

and another class such as:

```
class Bar {
    Foo foos[13];
};
```

If I construct a `Bar` object will it default initialize its 13 `Foo` member objects with the default initializer?

---

<strike>I've tested with Visual Studio 2008 and it is default initializing the `Foo` objects. I'd just like to know if that's standard behavior or Visual Studio special sauce.</strike>

It seems I had created the variables in a previously zeroed range.

Comment: @Amadeus Yup: "If `T` is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized", and default intialization is what happens to uninitialized member variables?

Comment: @Downvoter Could I get clarification on the downvote? If it's just the mandatory C++ downvote no need to respond.

Comment: Amadeus, you appear to have answered the question and backed it up with a link; could you post it as an answer?